# Finding elements using __utils__.getElementsByXPath in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, xpath, phantomjs, casperjs

A snippet from my casper.js test script is given below;

```
var refObject = undefined;

casper.then(function() {
  refObject = this.evaluate(function() {
    return __utils__.getElementsByXPath('//div[contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), " refObject ")]//a[contains(normalize-space(text()), normalize-space("SampleTest"))]//../../../..');
  });
  require('utils').dump(refObject);
  this.echo(refObject);
  test.assertTruthy(refObject);
});
```

Here inside evaluate function I am trying to get reference to a html element which looks as follows;

```
<div class="refObject">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
        <div class="accordion-toggle">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SampleTest</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Google Chrome (Ctrl+F), I tested the xpath and found to be referencing correctly. But when I execute the casperjs script I am getting output of `require('utils').dump(eobject)` as `[]` and `this.echo(eobject)` as blank. Does anyone has an idea about what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue of [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html). You cannot pass DOM elements from the page context to the outside. You have to have some primitive representation.

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will not work!**

You can check if this is the issue by returning the length of the array instead of the actual list.

The other problem might be the child search after you match the `a` element. Use

```
normalize-space("SampleTest"))]/../
-------------------------------^
```

instead of

```
normalize-space("SampleTest"))]//../
```

Your XPath expression is unnecessarily complex and maybe even error prone. This one is probably better:

```
//div[contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), " refObject ") and .//a[contains(text(), "SampleTest")]]
```